# How can I copy a node using linq?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to use linq to find MyNode where the name equals Foo, and make a copy of that node and add it to the XML but the new node should have name Bar, and then save the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyRoot>
  <MyNode Name="Foo">
    <Data Type="String">ABC</Data>
  </MyNode>
</MyRoot>
```

this code finds the node

```
    Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlFile)
    Dim sheet = From item In doc...<MyRoot>...<MyNode> Select item Where item.@Name = "Foo"
```

and I'm trying to use this to add the node and change the name.

```
    sheet.@Name = "Bar" 'After excecuting this, sheet becomes "Nothing"
    doc.Root.Add(sheet.First)
    doc.Save(outFile)
```

however, after the setting sheet.@Name to "Bar", then sheet becomes **Nothing**.  If I comment out that line, the output will have two nodes, both named Bar.  I suspect I am not doing this the "right way", in either of terms of changing the attribute or adding this to the XDocument (or both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c# version (will try to translate)

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
            var node = doc.Elements("MyRoot").Elements("MyNode").FirstOrDefault(m => m.Attribute("Name").Value == "Foo");
            var newNode = new XElement(node);
            newNode.SetAttributeValue("Name", "Bar");
            doc.Root.Add(newNode);
```

should be in vb

```
Dim doc as XDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlFile)
Dim sheet = From item...<MyNode>.FirstOrDefault(Function(m) m.@Name = "Foo")
Dim newSheet As New XElement(sheet)
newSheet.SetAttributeValue("Name", "Bar")
doc.Root.Add(newSheet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jim's answer got me pointed in the correct direction.  Here is the code I came up with

```
    Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlFile)
    Dim sheet = From item In doc...<MyRoot>...<MyNode> Select item Where item.@Name = "Foo"
    Dim copy As XElement = New XElement(sheet.First)
    copy.SetAttributeValue("Name", "Bar")
    doc.Root.Add(copy)
    doc.Save(outFile)
```